# Deleting extra images not working

Tags: html, css

i tried using this CSS3 slider code i been trying to get to work in dreamweaver.

It works fine but i only want to use 3 images to slide. For some reason it'll just keep continue to the 4th slider and 5th and just a black screen displays for those 2 images.

I tried taking out the HTML and the CSS and also the animation cycling 4th and 5th frames @keyframes, but for some reason it continues to still show and i have no clue how thats possibe.

Site link: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/

Demo link: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of animation.css

you need to time the animation right for what you need.

I played with it a bit in firefox, but it's not the best I could came up with.
This is what I have done. After deleting the last 2 frames and all css for them I played with the first 3. Here you go:

```
@-moz-keyframes cycle {
0%  { top:0px; opacity:1; }
33% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
66% { top:325px; opacity:0; }
100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; }

}
@-moz-keyframes cycletwo {
0%  { top:325px; opacity:0; }
33% { top:-352px; opacity:0; } 
66% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
100%{ top:325px; opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclethree {
0%  { top:325px; opacity:1; }
33% { top:352px; opacity:0; } 
66% { top:-352px; opacity:0; }
100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
}
```

Try timing it right to your needs as the site http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/ shows you how.

I would use a jQuery slider though.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks dude i relly appreciate it. thing is I'm having trouble implementing jquery in the 2013 free wordpress theme im using plus i dont want to slow down the page speed so that's why im only using pure css.  But i found another problem with this slider. it doesnt reset back to its original slide after the last side has been shown,   it doesnt work for any devices.  I tried watching the demo from my nexus tablet still no luck it will not return to its original slide just leave a black screen after its last slide